REFIT: Mix Post Workload Fields with Query String Params and Dynamic Header Items
Imagine I have a refit endpoint like this:
[Post("/api/v2/steps")]
Task CreateStep(CreateStepContext request);

I want to have one single context type that I can mix all the data items that the endpoint needs in:
public class CreateStepContext 
{
    public int Id {get; set;} // if not specified, comes from Body
    public [Query] string? StepType { get;set; }
    public [Header(name= "X-Client-ID")] string ClientId { get;set; }
}

Is it possible to make this work in Refit? If it's not available out of the box, how can I extend it? Thanks! 

I have reviewed the docs, It seems I can send a dictionary for all the Header items, but it cannot be a part of the context object.
There is also this DelegatingHandler that I can derive from, but all the examples I'm seeing are for static header items.

